# Update notification vibrate/ringtone

Tags: android, notifications, alert, notificationmanager

I am using the `NotificationManager` builder to show an alert in my app.  I know that the first parameter for the `notify` method is an id and the framework will update the notification if it is already visible, but if I set the alert to play a ringtone or vibrate, does the ringtone/vibration also fire if an alert is updated?

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nb.setContentTitle("title");
    nb.setContentText("message");
    nb.setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/alert", null, packageName));
    nb.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
    nb.setTicker("message");

    final Uri ringtone = Uri.parse(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("ringtone", getString(R.string.settings_default_ringtone)));

    nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    nb.setSound(ringtone);      
    nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    nb.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    Notification notification = nb.getNotification();

    nm.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Go to see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486677/how-to-stop-android-notification-ringtone-after-30-seconds>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tested this myself and the vibration/ringtones do fire off, even on an update.

UPDATE:
Just an update, if you are using `NotificationCompat.Builder` or `Notification.Builder` you can set `setOnlyAlertOnce` to only sound the ringtone/vibrate once.

Answer (score 0):

NotificationCompat.Builder  notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)

long[] v = {500,1000};
notificationBuilder.setVibrate(v);

Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);